# woocommerce cart quantity not showing correctly on cart page

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

When I add items to cart, it refreshes the quantity correctly in mini-cart widget, but when I go to cart page it always shows 1 item yet the subtotal is calculated correctly.

Ex: add 2 product x price is 400 so: 2 items x 400 subtotal 800

but in the cart page it shows 1 item x 400 subtotal 800. I add product to cart using the standard ajax call of woocommerce.

Any body can help me??

Thanks in advance...

Comment: It shows that in cart page you have one product and this one product single price is 400 but you have select two quantity and their subtotal is 800.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanx for your reply, i find the error by my self. I was trying to avoid negatives values on varibale products so i put the followng filter in the theme function.php:

```
/*add_filter('woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 'default_quantity_values');
function default_quantity_values( $default ){
    $default = array(
        'input_name'    => 'quantity',
        'input_value'   => '1',
        'max_value'     => '1000',
        'min_value'     => '1',
        'step'          => '1',
    );
    return $default;
}*/
```

As result, in my cart page, always reset the quantity value to one. Once i remove this filter, every thing work ok!!

Answer (score 0):

```
      function my_theme_wrapper_start()
          {
                  echo the_breadcrumb();
                  echo '<section role="main"><div class="wrap">';
           }

         function my_theme_wrapper_end()
         {
        echo '</div></section>';
          }

        function mytheme_prepare_woocommerce_wrappers()
       {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'woocommerce_output_content_wrapper', 10 );
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content', 'woocommerce_output_content_wrapper_end', 10);

    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'my_theme_wrapper_start', 10     );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content', 'my_theme_wrapper_end', 10 );
          }
  add_action( 'wp_head', 'mytheme_prepare_woocommerce_wrappers' );

   add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );
```

tyry this and see the result and please clear your query